# ZFS on Linux disk replacement best practices

Tags: zfsonlinux

I have an 8-bay NAS running Fedora 29 (kernel version 4.20.8) and zfs version 0.7.12. All of the drive bays are used for a zfs pool named “tank.” Here is the zpool layout:

```
tank
  mirror-0
    sda
    sdb
  mirror-1
    sdc
    sdd
  mirror-2
    sde
    sdf
  cache
    sdg
  spare
    sdh
```

One of the drives (sdb) is failing SMART tests with uncorrected offline reallocated sectors, but still shows as “ONLINE” by ‘zpool status.’ I want to physically replace sdb with a new drive (sdi).

Since there are no available physical bays, I plan to use the following to replace the drive:

```
 zpool offline tank sdb
 zpool replace tank sdb sdh
 zpool detach tank sdb
 echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/block/sdb/device/delete
 # Remove the physical hard drive associated with sdb and plug in new physical drive mapped to sdi
```

I do not know how to best proceed from here. Is it better to:
(a) just add sdi as a new spare (leaving sdh as a permanent replacement for sdb)
`zpool add tank spare sdi`
(b) replace sdh with sdi and have sdh go back the spare drive pool?

```
 zpool replace tank sdi sdh
 zpool detach tank sdh
```

In this case “better” means less administrative complexity going forward (e.g. if sdh goes bad when applying option (a), would a ‘detach,’ or other, command fail or produce unexpected results since sdh used to be a spare?)? Also, I’m uncertain if I am missing/ incorrect in steps under option (b).

Notes:

1. pool names simplified (e.g vdevs are mapped ids)
2. know the kernel/ zfs are ancient, but solving this failing drive ahead of upgrade
3. Controller card and bays support hot swapping
4. Searched and read topics on ZoL disk replacement as well as Oracle’s docs, but haven’t seen a topic on best practice (sorry if I missed it)

Comment: Is there a raid active on hardware level?

Comment: No raid at the hardware level. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference between the options when all is said and done — drives are interchangeable. "Just add `sdi` as the new spare" requires fewer steps and minimizes the amount of time that you spend in a resyncing state, so it's the natural choice.

Comment: Marking this as the answer as it works, though prototyped a file-based zpool to confirm subsequent maintenance (at least for replacement of a failed in-use spare) wasn’t impacted by this approach. Thank you for the time.

Answer (score 2):

First of all create a good backup.

Then

1:(Offline the failing drive:)
`zpool offline tank sdb`

2:(Replace sdb with sdi:)
`zpool replace tank sdb sdi`

3:Detach the old drive (sdh):
`zpool detach tank sdh`

Comment: Thank you, and that is the process I mentioned in my original question (though I did not include the pool name in the command syntax…updated that above). My question was about what follows the removal of the disk (ie leave spare as permanent replacement and add new disk as spare or temporarily use spare with  procedure to replace the faulty disk and restore spare pool with the original spare). Please note that sdh is the newly purchased disk (sdb is the faulty disk).

Comment: Also, please note that there is no open bay (so I can’t do a straightforward ```zpool replace tank sdb sdi```)

Comment: There is some confusion (typo(s)?) going on with this answer. Step 3 is detaching sdh but sdh wasn't referenced in the previous steps. Step 2 is using sdi but sdi can't exist until the failing drive is replaced, because there isn't a drive bay for it. And the question covers/explains what they are going to do about that anyways (use the spare), they are wondering what to do after that stage...